# using android-support-v4.jar and ViewPagerExtensions.jar together causes jar mismatch

Tags: android

how to resolve issue of jar mismatch i need to use both libraries ?
i am working on integrating ViewPagerExtensions.jar in my project library available from https://github.com/astuetz/ViewPagerExtensions

any help or advice would be greatly appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This error means you have two different versions of the `android-support-v4.jar`, one in your project and one in the ViewPagerExtensions library.
Simply replace one or both jars by the most recent `android-support-v4.jar`.

Answer (score 1):

just copy one .jar from one of the libs folders and put it on the other librarys libs folder. So that both libraries use the same version of the support library.

Answer (score 0):

This is a more elegant fix than deleting and adding files!

You just need to :

Right Click the project App Free
Go To "Android Tools" > "Add Support Library"
Approve the permissions and let it update the library
Repeat this process for the project App Library
The Android Support Library will then be in sync (: